# Setting a default page in the Xamarin.Forms shell menu

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.shell

Using the Xaminals example, I'm trying to set the default startup page. Here's the relevant code from the xaml:

```xml
<FlyoutItem Route="animals" x:Name="shellAnimals"
            Title="Animals"
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <Tab Title="Domestic" x:Name="shellDomestic"
         Route="domestic"
         Icon="paw.png">
        <ShellContent Route="cats" x:Name="shellCats"
                      Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                      Title="Cats"
                      Icon="cat.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Route="dogs" x:Name="shellDogs"
                      Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                      Title="Dogs"
                      Icon="dog.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <ShellContent Route="monkeys" x:Name="shellMonkeys"
                  Style="{StaticResource MonkeysShell}"
                  Title="Monkeys"
                  Icon="monkey.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />
    <ShellContent Route="elephants" x:Name="shellElephants"
                  Style="{StaticResource ElephantsShell}"
                  Title="Elephants"
                  Icon="elephant.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ElephantsPage}" />
    <ShellContent Route="bears" x:Name="shellBears"
                  Style="{StaticResource BearsShell}"
                  Title="Bears"
                  Icon="bear.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:BearsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

In the code behind I can successfully set the default startup page.

For example, the dogs page:

```cs
shellAnimals.CurrentItem.CurrentItem = shellDogs;
```

But on the bears page:

```cs
// This works, but I don't like the indexing. Will give trouble on dynamic menu's
shellAnimals.CurrentItem = shellAnimals.Items[3];

// This doesn't work, but I don't understand why. It gives a null reference exception in the Xamarin Shell code, on the PushAsync
shellAnimals.CurrentItem = shellBears;

// This shows the bears page at startup, but when I click on an item in the listview, I also get a null reference error
CurrentItem = shellBears;
```

1. Why doesn't the second/third snippet work?
2. How can I set the default page to the bears page without using the indexer?

Can't find anything on this subject except [Set default tab on Xamarin Forms Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56812252/set-default-tab-on-xamarin-forms-shell) but that doesn't answer it.

Comment: Based on Jack's answer below I made a detailed article about this: http://xamarinformsdumps.data.blog/2019/12/16/selecting-a-default-flyout-menu-item-in-xamarin-forms-shell
Hopefully this can help anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't the second/third snippet work?

The second snippet:

`shellAnimals.CurrentItem` is a variable which type is `ShellSection` while your shellBears is kind of `ShellContent`.

The third snippet:

When you use `CurrentItem` directly in the shell class, that is `Shell.CurrentItem` and it's a `ShellItem`.

> How can I set the default page to the bears page without using the
>   indexer?

In your Xaml:

```
    <ShellSection x:Name="shellBears" Title="Bears"
                      Icon="bear.png">
        <ShellContent Route="bears"
                      Style="{StaticResource BearsShell}"                                                   
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:BearsPage}" />
    </ShellSection >
```

And in code behind:

```
    shellAnimals.CurrentItem = shellBears;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the current page in XAML, as per the documentation [Set-the-current-flyoutitem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#set-the-current-flyoutitem). This would then mean your `Shell` tag, you would add `CurrentItem="{x:Reference shellBears}"1.

Additionally, I see in your second code behind snippet you are missing another `.CurrentItem` step when compared to the dogs example that you say works. Can you try `shellAnimals.CurrentItem.CurrentItem = shellBears;`