# CurrentItem does not work on iOS but it does work on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile

`CurrentItem` does not work on iOS but it does work on Android, I am using xamarin.
This is my code:

```cs
Shell.Current.CurrentItem = new MyPageTest();
```

Launch this exception:

```
system.NullReferenceExcepion
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Is there any way to change the CurrentItem?

Comment: Can you please add more code about where you call `Shell.Current.CurrentItem = new MyPageTest();`? In my understanding, `Shell.Current.CurrentItem`  point to currently selected `Xamarin.Forms.ShellItem` or `Xamarin.Forms.FlyoutItem`  and it should be a existing page instead of a new page. Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248713/setting-a-default-page-in-the-xamarin-forms-shell-menu/59259763#59259763) for more information.

Comment: I'm calling from a view or page that doesn't have shell. That is all my code is just a button to change the CurrentItem.

Comment: Can you please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to us? I can't reproduce the problem on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I deleted Xamarin.forms from my project and Installed again from nuget. and this code `Shell.Current.CurrentItem = new MyPageTest();` is correct, but doesn't get the correct result I change by  `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//myshellapproot/shellcontentview");`

Comment: You can mark it as the right answer which will help more people with same problem:).